# three.js javascript/raycasting code not compatible with retina display macs

Tags: javascript, three.js, retina-display, raycasting

Does anyone have an explanation as to why the interactive cubes below do not work on retina display macs?

http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes.html

The code works in Firefox, Safari and Chrome in the non retina macbook, but does not work in the macs with a retina display.

Macs: macbook pro retina display,imac retina display, macbook pro 2011 (no retina display) all running Yosemite

Browser Versions:  Firefox 36, Safari Version 8.0.3 (10600.3.18), Chrome Version 40.0.2214.115 (64-bit)

Comment: Does [this three.js demo](http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_interactive_particles.html) work? If so, I expect it is a device pixel ratio issue.

Comment: The demo works on an old mac.

Comment: Does the demo I linked to work on a mac with a retina display?

Comment: Hello WestLangley, I apologize for the delay, yes your demo works just fine on the retina display mac as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `renderer.setSize()`, the renderer's `domElement` or canvas, is scaled by the pixel ratio.

```
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

Then, in the [interactive cubes example](http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes.html), the normalized mouse coordinates are set like so:

```
mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;
```

This will cause a problem with devices that have a pixel ratio not equal to 1.

Note that in the [interactive particles example](http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_interactive_particles.html), the normalized mouse coordinates are computed differently, and there is no problem.

```
mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
```

As a work-around, use the second pattern.

We may have to revisit how device pixel ratio is handled in future versions of the library.

EDIT: @mrdoob suggests the following pattern as a solution:

```
mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;
```

three.js r.70

Comment: Just note that for some reason clientWidth/Height will trigger [reflows](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a). An optional approach is to cache the width and height and only update on resize/scroll (`getBoundingClientRect()` can also be used with the element, but also this causes reflow :-/ ).